# conditional Query elastic search using java client not working

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to write a fetch query and delete document using elastic search API, which should have below two conditions

1. if accountType is not "Prepaid" OR
2. if accountType is not "Postpaid" AND ProductName is not "SIM" AND
3. timestamp is less than 30 days

I have tried with the **below code** but it does not fetch the right documents. intent is to fetch all these document and delete from Elastic search index

```
QueryBuilder query = QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
                .should(QueryBuilders.boolQuery().mustNot(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("ACCOUNT_TYPE", "PREPAID")))
                .should(QueryBuilders.boolQuery().mustNot(QueryBuilders.matchPhraseQuery("ACCOUNT_TYPE","POSTPAID"))
                .mustNot(QueryBuilders.matchPhraseQuery("PRODUCT_NAME", "SIM"))).minimumShouldMatch(1)
                .must(QueryBuilders.rangeQuery(LASTUPDATED_TIMESTAMP_PARAM).lt(interval.getDelDateString()));
```

approch 2: I have also tried to run the above generate query in Kibana dev tools and still it doesnt give right results.

please suggest me where i am going wrong with the above code to satisfy the condition of fetching the data.

**Query formed is something like below post @Val resposne**

{"bool":{"filter":[{"range":{"lastupdatedTimestamp":{"from":null,"to":"2022-03-12T22:00:00","include_lower":true,"include_upper":false,"boost":1}}}],"should":[{"bool":{"must_not":[{"match":{"ACCOUNT_TYPE":{"query":"PREPAID","operator":"OR","prefix_length":0,"max_expansions":50,"fuzzy_transpositions":true,"lenient":false,"zero_terms_query":"NONE","auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query":true,"boost":1}}}],"adjust_pure_negative":true,"boost":1}},{"bool":{"must_not":[{"match":{"ACCOUNT_TYPE":{"query":"POSTPAID","operator":"OR","prefix_length":0,"max_expansions":50,"fuzzy_transpositions":true,"lenient":false,"zero_terms_query":"NONE","auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query":true,"boost":1}}},{"match":{"PRODUCT_NAME":{"query":"SIM","operator":"OR","prefix_length":0,"max_expansions":50,"fuzzy_transpositions":true,"lenient":false,"zero_terms_query":"NONE","auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query":true,"boost":1}}}],"adjust_pure_negative":true,"boost":1}}],"adjust_pure_negative":true,"minimum_should_match":"1","boost":1}}

Comment: are you using new java api client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the elastic search java api call to do a conditional fetch of records and delete it later

```
QueryBuilder query = QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
         .filter(QueryBuilders.rangeQuery(LASTUPDATED_TIMESTAMP_PARAM).lt(interval.getDelDateString()))     
         .filter(QueryBuilders.boolQuery().mustNot(QueryBuilders.matchQuery(ACCOUNT_TYPE, "PREPAID")))
         .must(QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
                       .should(QueryBuilders.boolQuery().mustNot(QueryBuilders.matchQuery(ACCOUNT_TYPE,"POSTPAID")))
                       .should(QueryBuilders.boolQuery().mustNot(QueryBuilders.matchQuery(PRODUCT_NAME, "SIM"))).minimumShouldMatch(1));
```

this is satisfying the conidtion to fetch all the non PREPAID orders and non POSPAID whose product name is not SIM.

Comment: Good you figured out, but it's not at all the same query logic you identified in your question. Also the additional top-level bool/must is useless, you should bring the bool/should at the top level

Comment: would love to correct Val but this is actually worked. with this approach i first removed all the non PREPAID document and over that i applied a condition of point 2 in the initial question. BTW real thanks for extending your kind inputs and time.

Comment: No problem, if you found the correct constraint for your use case, I was just mentioning for those who'll read this thread in the future that the constraint in your question and the code in your answer don't match.

Answer (score 1):

You have some boolean logic issues. Try this way:

```
QueryBuilder query = QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
         .filter(QueryBuilders.rangeQuery(LASTUPDATED_TIMESTAMP_PARAM).lt(interval.getDelDateString()))             
         .minimumShouldMatch(1)
         .should(QueryBuilders.boolQuery().mustNot(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("ACCOUNT_TYPE", "PREPAID")))
         .should(QueryBuilders.boolQuery()    
                    .mustNot(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("ACCOUNT_TYPE","POSTPAID"))
                    .mustNot(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("PRODUCT_NAME", "SIM")));
```

Comment: thanks for the revert, I have made the changes accordingly and when i execute undesired data( unintended data also getting deleted )

Query formed pasting in the next comment due to word limit

Comment: unable to paste the query still.. how should i share it ?

Comment: You can update your question, or [gist it](https://gist.github.com/)

Comment: updated the question with formed query. please check and help me to understand and derive the solution

Comment: The query looks ok according to the requirements you've listed, except that you should use `filter` instead of `must`, that's the main difference. Try with `filter` instead of `must`

Comment: I used exactly what you shared that is filter. my intent is to delete the document >30 days with the condition "(ACCOUNT_TYPE != "PREPAID") OR (ACCOUNT_TYPE !="POSTPAID" AND PRODUCT_NAME !="SIM") ". However, it is deleting the records even with ACCOUNT_TYPE as "PREPAID" and the records with OR condition. need quick help on this.

Comment: In the query you shared I see a `must` so it's not exactly what I provided in my answer, please check again

Comment: ooh, let me cross check whether I referred the correct logs then. will get back with verified content

Comment: updating the latest query with filter. here everything is getting deleted <30 days.

Comment: could you please help me here. i have updated the latest query and its deleting evething <30 days

Comment: By "timestamp is less than 30 days" do you mean older than 30 days or between 30 days ago and now?

Comment: older than 30 days data.

Comment: Maybe the two should conditions are too permissive and include everything?

Comment: hey Val, i am able to figure it out. I am just adding that answer. thanks for you prompt response. appreciate it.